# Given a list of coordinates in the first quadrant, calculate how many right triangles can be formed which have one side parallel to x-axis

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

Given a list of coordinates in the `first quadrant`, calculate how many **right triangles** can be formed from these which have one side parallel to `x-axis` and one side parallel to `y-axis`.

Recently I took part in a programming competition, more specifically INOI(*Indian National Olympiad n Informatics*) and this was the first out of two questions in the paper.

Basically I figured any 3 points of type `(a,y)` `(x,y)` `(x,b)` would form such a triangle but couldn't manage anything better, and in the end just wrote a naive **O(n^3)** solution (*and so did all my friends*).

Can anyone suggest a better way?

And please, THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK.

Comment: What's the maximum number of points you can be given?

Comment: 10^4 I think and 1s is the time limit. don't remember clearly whether it was >10^4 or 10^4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets `numX[i] = how many points have i as their X coordinate` and `numY[i] = how many points have i as their Y coordinate`.

We will count how many triangles with the required property exist for a certain point `p`. Without loss of generality, we can assume that `p` is the point where the triangles make their right angle.

For this to happen, we need a point with the same `Y` coordinate and one with the same `X` coordinate. So how about this algorithm:

```
compute numX and numY in O(n).
num = 0
for each point p in the given list of points
    num += (numX[p.X] - 1)*(numY[p.Y] - 1)

output num
```

Basically, we can combine each point with the same `X` coordinate with each point with the same `Y` coordinate to get the required triangle. We subtract `1` so as not to count `p` itself.

This will run in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I agree with IVlad there.
the input can be directly stored in a 2*N array, and at the same time the count for every x and y should be stored in numX and numY... then it's just wat IVlad said...